# Generating stock prices using geometric brownian motion

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, random, simulation

I am writing a c++ class of "A simple least squares approach" by Longstaff and Schwartz. I have only finished writing a function for creating the stock price paths using geometric brownian motion. I am still a bit of a novice when it comes to writing classes in c++ and I just want to see if there is anything I can improve on with what I have written so far.

That being said, should I include pointers or any other type of data structure to make the code better?

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "LSM.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){
    const double r = 0.04;          // Riskless interest rate
    const double q = 0.0;           // Divident yield
    const double sigma = 0.20;      // Volatility of stock
    const double T = 1;             // Time (expiry)
    const int N = 2;                // Number of time steps
    const double K = 100.0;         // Strike price
    const double S0 = 102.0;        // Initial stock price
    const int M = 4;                // Number of paths
    const int R = 2;                // Choice of basis for Laguerre polynomial

    LSM Option_value(r,q,sigma,T,N,K,S0,M,R);











    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


#ifndef LSM_H
#define LSM_H

class LSM {
public:
    // Overload Constructor
    LSM(const double, const double, const double, const int, const int, const double, const double, const int, const int);

    // Destructor
    ~LSM();

    // Generate M paths of stock prices (Geometric Brownian Motion)
    vector<double> GBM(const int, const int, const double, const double, const double, const double, const double);



private:
    // Member variables
    double new_r;
    double new_q;
    double new_sigma;
    int new_T;
    int new_N;
    double new_K;
    double new_S0;
    int new_M;
    int new_R;

};




#endif
```

and here is the .cpp file correlated to the header file above:

```
#include "LSM.h"


LSM::LSM( const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const int T, const int N, const double K, const double S0, const int M, const int R){
    new_r = r;
    new_q = q;
    new_sigma = sigma;
    new_T = T;
    new_N = N;
    new_K = K;
    new_S0 = S0;
    new_M = M;
    new_R = R;

    vector<double> v;
    v = GBM(new_M, new_N, new_T, new_r, new_q, new_sigma, new_S0);
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }


}

LSM::~LSM(){

}

vector<double> LSM::GBM(const int M, const int N, const double T, const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const double S0){
    double dt =  T/N;
    vector<double> Z;
    vector<double> S;
    S.push_back(S0);
    mt19937 e2(time(0));
    normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Z.push_back(dist(e2));
    }
    double drift  = exp(dt*(r-0.5*sigma*sigma));
    double vol = sqrt(sigma*sigma*dt);
    for(int i = 1; i < M; i++){
        S.push_back(S[i-1] * drift * exp(vol*Z[i]));
    }
    return S;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a really interesting use of Brownian motion! Neat idea! Here are some suggestions for improving the code:

## Avoid `using namespace std`

In general, using `using namespace std` is a bad idea. In a header, it's a very bad idea. [Here's one description of why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice#1452738).

## Naming

You should name your function arguments in the header so a user of your code knows what they represent. For example, in the future, you might compile this into a library to include in other programs, and ship just the header and the compiled library. If you do that, a user of your library will have no idea what the arguments to the LSM constructor are. (And remember that that user may be a future you who doesn't remember all the details of the implementation!)

I'd also recommend that you use better names than 1 letter names that may be meaningless or worse, confusing to readers of your code. You have some great ideas for what the names should be in the comments in `main()`. Instead of adding comments to explain the names, just name the variables what you wrote in the comments. For example, instead of `r`, call it `risklessInterestRate`. Instead of `q`, call it `dividendYield`. Yes, it takes a little bit longer to type, but those few extra seconds of typing will end up saving minutes or hours of frustration if you get 2 of the variables with similar names confused (like `M` and `N`).

## Headers

Only include what you need. Only include it where you need it. Your `main()` function doesn't need any header other than `LSM.h`, so it should be the only thing you include there. `LSM.h` doesn't need any of the files it has included except for `<vector>`. `LSM.cpp` should include those files instead because it *does* use them. It might not seem like a big deal now, but once your project gets a little bigger, including the wrong files or including files you don't need can really slow down a compile.

## Constructors

In C++, the constructor should never call a virtual method of its own class because it's not yet fully constructed. Luckily your code does not do that. But it does call a non-virtual method. When I see that, it raises a red flag to me, because it's fairly common for a non-virtual method to later become virtual if a subclass needs to override it. For that reason, I tend to avoid calling any (non-static) methods of the same class within a constructor. Furthermore, the `LSM::GBM` function doesn't use any member variables or change any state in the object or call any member functions of `LSM`, so it could be implemented as a free-standing static function inside `LSM.cpp`. (Unless, of course, you're going to want other code outside the class to call it, in which case it should probably be a static member function of the `LSM` class.)

## `const`

Nice use of `const`! So few people use it, so it's really refreshing to see it being used well. Good work!

Comment: *Some* of the use of `const` is nice - but declaring primitive arguments `const` in the prototype declaration serves no purpose, and is needless clutter IMO.  (Keep them in the implementation declaration, of course - they do serve a useful purpose there).

Comment: For the constructor part of your answer I had a question or two. I am not going to write another class or subclass (unless recommended) but what I was going to do was write more functions within it to be used within the LSM() constructor as I will need more functions to perform the actual valuation of the American option contract. Is there anything wrong with that? Is there a better way as in making more subclasses that will be public with LSM?

Comment: If you're not going to be subclassing it, then it's probably fine. The way your class is at the moment, you're putting data into it, and it's doing a calculation in the constructor, and the constructor prints out the results. Usually, one object will hold some data and possibly process it, and another object will print the data out. (This is often referred to as separating your business logic from your display logic.) As it stands right now, there's no way to get data out of an `LSM` object. That seems a little odd (though I admit, I don't know anything about option contracts).

Answer (score 2):

The structure of this code seems difficult to work with, and much of the code is not where I'd expect it to be - for example, I wouldn't expect the constructor to be streaming to `std::cout`.

Let's look at the design, with an object-oriented viewpoint.  Mathematically, each result depends only on the immediately-preceding results and the supplied parameters, so we could write a class that acts as a **generator**, with a public interface that looks something like this:

```
class LSM
{
public:
   LSM(/*parameters*/);  // constructor

   float operator()();   // generate next result

   void reset(double S0); // optional
};
```

If we want to fill a vector with results, we can do it, using one of the `std::generate()` family:

```
std::vector<float> v;
v.reserve(M);
LSM generator{/*parameters*/};
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), M, generator);
```

Equally, we could fill a `std::array<float,M>` or a plain C array of size `M`, if `M` is constant.

We can print out the contents of the vector in any of the usual ways, so there's no need to provide that in our class.

Some other minor points:

- We can cut out the unused parameters, and pre-combine the ones that are always used together.
- Prefer to use initializers for members, rather than assignment
  in the the body of the constructor.
- There's no need for a destructor, so we can simply omit it and let the compiler generate a suitable default.  (If we were writing a base class to be inherited from, we could write `virtual ~LSM() = default;` to use the compiler's implementation but make it virtual.)
- We probably want floating-point division of `T/N` rather than integer division.  `double dt = 1/2;` will always set `dt` to zero.
- The include guards can surround the whole header, including its own includes, to simplify the compilation and to make them easier to see.
- Don't `using namespace`, in general.  **Never** `using namespace` in a header.
- Prefer `<cmath>` and `<ctime>` over their C equivalents (but remember the namespace qualifier when using the names they define).
- `return 0;` is optional from the `main()` function.

---

## Revised code

Here's what I obtained after making the changes I suggest:

```
#ifndef LSM_H
#define LSM_H

#include <random>

class LSM {
public:
    // Overload Constructor
    LSM(double riskless_rate,
        double volatility,
        int expiry_time,
        int time_steps,
        double initial_price);

    // Generate next value, using Geometric Brownian Motion
    double operator()();


private:
    // configuration constants
    double drift;
    double vol;

    // state
    double current_price;
    std::mt19937 random_source;
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist;
};

#endif
```

```
// implementation

#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

LSM::LSM(const double r, const double sigma,
         const int t, const int n,
         const double S0)
    : drift{std::exp((r-0.5*sigma*sigma)*t/n)},
      vol{sigma*std::sqrt(1.*t/n)},
      current_price{S0},
      random_source{std::mt19937::result_type(std::time(0))},
      dist{0.0, 1.0}
{
}

double LSM::operator()()
{
    const double Zi = dist(random_source);
    return current_price *= drift * std::exp(vol*Zi);
}
```

```
// test program

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    LSM option_value{
        0.04,               // Riskless interest rate
        0.20,               // Volatility of stock
        1,                  // Time (expiry)
        2,                  // Number of time steps
        102.0               // Initial stock price
    };

    const int M = 4;            // Number of steps    

    std::array<double, M> values;
    std::generate(std::begin(values), std::end(values), option_value);

    std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values),
              std::ostream_iterator<double>{std::cout, ", "});
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

## Future directions

I understand that the use case for this class is to generate a statistical spread of price values.  Once those are generated, this generator isn't needed again.  So you'd construct an `LSM` and use it, but probably not keep a reference to it.

For example:

```
class OptionParameters; // encapsulate r, q, sigma, etc

class RandomWalks
{
     // one array of time series per run
     std::array<std::array<double>> prices;

public:
     RandomWalks(const OptionParameters& params)
     {
          for (auto time_series: prices) {
               LSM generator(params);
               std::generate(prices.begin(), prices.end(), generator);
          }
     }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your submission. I was following the structure of a class from a youtube tutorial so I thought it was correct. Your code seems a bit daunting to me at some parts so I am not sure if I could really use it but thank you.

Comment: Ok, to understand your point let me ask a question. I have the LSM class but I also have a function within it called GBM that I need to use within the LSM() constructor to perform the valuation of the American option. Are you saying that I should just make a GBM class and any other functions I make that I need make them into smaller classes? I hope that makes sense

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I could write a GBM class and just make the LSM class a friend. Does that make running the LSM class more efficient or faster by making the functions into smaller classes?

Comment: I've added a paragraph and example to give you pointers to get to the next review.  I think the comments here are now all redundant (I'm removing mine, and I suggest you do likewise).