# Writting “A Simple Least-Squares Approach” by Longstaff and Schwartz into a C++ class

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, eigen

**Background:**

I have posted a similar question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177918/writting-a-simple-least-squares-approach-by-longstaff-and-schwartz-pricing-am). I followed the suggestions of @ Ben Steffan and made the appropriate changes despite number 6 that I did not understand and number 7.

**Question:**

As it stands right now I want to make sure that I am writing this class correctly and as efficiently as possible using the Eigen library. Any suggestions on improving my code are greatly appreciated.

Here is my header file:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>







#ifndef LSM_H
#define LSM_H




class LSM {
public:
    // Overload Constructor
    LSM(const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const int T, const int N, const double K, const double S0, const int M, const int R);

    // Destructor
    ~LSM();

    // Generate the Laguerre Polynomials
    Eigen::MatrixXd Laguerre(Eigen::VectorXd, const int);

    // Generate Gaussian noise
    Eigen::VectorXd Gaussian(const double M);

    // Generate M paths of stock prices (Geometric Brownian Motion)
    Eigen::VectorXd GBM(const int M, const int N, const double T, const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const double S0);

    // Generate time paths
    Eigen::VectorXd Timepaths(const double min, const double max, const double N);

    // Payoff of call option
    Eigen::VectorXd CallPayoff(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);

    // Payoff of put option
    Eigen::VectorXd PutPayoff(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);

    // Find function for finding the paths that are in the money (call option)
    Eigen::VectorXd Findcallpath(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);

    // Find function for finding the paths that are in the money (put option)
    Eigen::VectorXd Findputpath(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);

    // Find price of call given path
    Eigen::VectorXd Findcallprices(Eigen::VectorXd path, Eigen::VectorXd S);

    // Find price of put given path
    Eigen::VectorXd Findputprices(Eigen::VectorXd path, Eigen::VectorXd S);

    // Find return of call (stock price - strike price)
    Eigen::VectorXd Findcallreturn(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);

    // Find return of put (strike price - stock price)
    Eigen::VectorXd Findputreturn(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);

    // Using Two-sided Jacobi SVD decomposition of a rectangular matrix
    Eigen::VectorXd Jacobi(Eigen::MatrixXd L, Eigen::VectorXd Y);






private:
    // Member variables
    double new_r;
    double new_q;
    double new_sigma;
    int new_T;
    int new_N;
    double new_K;
    double new_S0;
    int new_M;
    int new_R;

};






#endif
```

Here is the associated .cpp file for the header above:

```
#include "LSM.h"


LSM::LSM(const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const int T, const int N, const double K, const double S0, const int M, const int R){
    new_r = r;
    new_q = q;
    new_sigma = sigma;
    new_T = T;
    new_N = N;
    new_K = K;
    new_S0 = S0;
    new_M = M;
    new_R = R;

    // The LSM algorithm

    Eigen::VectorXd S = GBM(new_M, new_N, new_T, new_r, new_q, new_sigma, new_S0);
    Eigen::VectorXd t = Timepaths(0.0,new_T,new_N);
    Eigen::VectorXd P = PutPayoff(S,new_K);                                             // Payoff at time T

    for(int i = new_N; i >= 2; i--){
        Eigen::VectorXd Z = Gaussian(new_M);

    }





}


Eigen::MatrixXd LSM::Laguerre(Eigen::VectorXd X, const int R){
    int n = X.rows();
        int m = R + 1;
        Eigen::MatrixXd value(n, m);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
                if (R == 1) {
                    value(i,0) = 1.0;
                    value(i,1) = -X(i) + 1.0;
                }
                else if (R == 2) {
                    value(i,0) = 1.0;
                    value(i,1) = -X(i) + 1.0;
                    value(i,2) = 1.0/2.0*(2 - 4*X(i) + X(i)*X(i));
                }
                else if (R == 3) {
                    value(i,0) = 1.0;
                    value(i,1) = -X(i) + 1.0;
                    value(i,2) = 1.0/2.0*(2 - 4*X(i) + X(i)*X(i));
                    value(i,3) = 1.0/6.0*(6.0 - 18.0*X(i,0) + 9.0*X(i)*X(i) - pow((double)X(i,0),3.0));
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::Timepaths(const double min, const double max, const double N){
    Eigen::VectorXd m(N+1);
         double delta = (max-min)/N;

         for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
                 m(i) = min + i*delta;
         }
        return m;
}

Eigen::VectorXd Gaussian(const double M){
    std::mt19937 e2(time(0));
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    Eigen::VectorXd Z(M);

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Z(i) = dist(e2);
    }
    return Z;
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::GBM(const int M, const int N, const double T, const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const double S0){
    double dt = T/N;
    Eigen::VectorXd Z(M);
    Eigen::VectorXd S(M);
    S(0) = S0;
    std::mt19937 e2(time(0));
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Z(i) = dist(e2);
    }
    double drift  = exp(dt*((r - q)-0.5*sigma*sigma));
    double vol = sqrt(sigma*sigma*dt);

    for(int i = 1; i < M; i++){
        S(i) = S(i-1) * drift * exp(vol * Z(i));
    }
    return S;
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::CallPayoff(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K){
    Eigen::VectorXd C(S.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
            if(S(i) - K > 0){
                C(i) = S(i) - K;
            }else{
                C(i) = 0.0;
            }
        }
        return C;
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::PutPayoff(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K){
    Eigen::VectorXd P(S.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
            if(K - S(i) > 0){
                P(i) = K - S(i);
            }else{
                P(i) = 0.0;
            }
        }
        return P;
}


Eigen::VectorXd LSM::Findcallpath(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K){
    Eigen::VectorXd path(S.size());
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
        if(S(i) - K > 0){
            path(count) = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    path.conservativeResize(count);
    return path;
}
Eigen::VectorXd LSM::Findputpath(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K){
    Eigen::VectorXd path(S.size());
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
        if(K - S(i) > 0){
            path(count) = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    path.conservativeResize(count);
    return path;
}

Eigen::VectorXd Findcallprices(Eigen::VectorXd path, Eigen::VectorXd S){
    Eigen::VectorXd C(path.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++){
        C(i) = S(path(i));
    }
    return C;
}

Eigen::VectorXd Findputprices(Eigen::VectorXd path, Eigen::VectorXd S){
    Eigen::VectorXd P(path.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++){
        P(i) = S(path(i));
    }
    return P;
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::Jacobi(Eigen::MatrixXd L, Eigen::VectorXd Y){
    return L.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(Y);
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::Findcallreturn(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K){
    Eigen::VectorXd C_return(S.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
        C_return(i) = (S(i) - K);
    }
    return C_return;
}

Eigen::VectorXd LSM::Findputreturn(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K){
    Eigen::VectorXd P_return(S.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
        P_return(i) = (K - S(i));
    }
    return P_return;
}
```

Here is the main.cpp file that I will use once I finish the algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LSM.h"



int main(){
    const double r = 0.04;          // Riskless interest rate
    const double q = 0.0;           // Divident yield
    const double sigma = 0.20;      // Volatility of stock
    const double T = 1;             // Time (expiry)
    const int N = 2;                // Number of time steps
    const double K = 100.0;         // Strike price
    const double S0 = 102.0;        // Initial stock price
    const int M = 4;                // Number of paths
    const int R = 2;                // Choice of basis for Laguerre polynomial

    LSM Option_value(r,q,sigma,T,N,K,S0,M,R);













    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you intentionally insert so many repeated empty lines?

Comment: You said you made the appropriate changes from my suggestion except for number 6 and 7, but to me it looks like you have ignored most of my other suggestions as well. For example, I don't see what you did about points 3 and 4, and point 5 is only implemented partially.  Same for points 7, 8 and 10. I highly suggest you implement those first (and ask if you don't understand anything) before opening up another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Why is this procedural code being shoehorned into a class?

---

## Include (only) what you use

Of the standard library headers included by `LSM.h`, exactly zero of these are used:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
```

(and I'd avoid mixing the C-style `<time.h>` in with the C++ish `<cmath>` in new code, too)

The Eigen headers are overkill; the only one needed for the header is

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

## Don't declare primitives `const` in method prototypes

For example:

```
class LSM {
    Eigen::VectorXd CallPayoff(Eigen::VectorXd S, const double K);
};
```

`K` is passed by value, so the caller isn't interested in whether this method might modify its copy (obviously, a `const` declaration is useful *where the method is implemented*).

On the other hand, seriously consider passing `S` as a reference to `const`.

It seems that none of the methods actually use anything from the class instance, nor are called from outside the class, so they can all be declared `static` and `private`:

```
#ifndef LSM_H
#define LSM_H

#include <Eigen/Core>

class LSM {
public:
    // Overload Constructor
    LSM(double r, double q, double sigma, int T, int N, double K, double S0, int M, int R);

    // Destructor
    ~LSM();

private:
    // Generate the Laguerre Polynomials
    static Eigen::MatrixXd Laguerre(const Eigen::VectorXd&, int);

    // Generate Gaussian noise
    static Eigen::VectorXd Gaussian(double M);

    // Generate M paths of stock prices (Geometric Brownian Motion)
    static Eigen::VectorXd GBM(int M, int N, double T, double r, double q, double sigma, double S0);

    // Generate time paths
    static Eigen::VectorXd Timepaths(double min, double max, double N);

    // Payoff of call option
    static Eigen::VectorXd CallPayoff(const Eigen::VectorXd& S, double K);

    // Payoff of put option
    static Eigen::VectorXd PutPayoff(const Eigen::VectorXd& S, double K);

    // Find function for finding the paths that are in the money (call option)
    static Eigen::VectorXd Findcallpath(const Eigen::VectorXd& S, double K);

    // Find function for finding the paths that are in the money (put option)
    static Eigen::VectorXd Findputpath(const Eigen::VectorXd& S, double K);

    // Find price of call given path
    static Eigen::VectorXd Findcallprices(const Eigen::VectorXd& path, const Eigen::VectorXd& S);

    // Find price of put given path
    static Eigen::VectorXd Findputprices(const Eigen::VectorXd& path, const Eigen::VectorXd& S);

    // Find return of call (stock price - strike price)
    static Eigen::VectorXd Findcallreturn(const Eigen::VectorXd& S, double K);

    // Find return of put (strike price - stock price)
    static Eigen::VectorXd Findputreturn(const Eigen::VectorXd& S, double K);

    // Using Two-sided Jacobi SVD decomposition of a rectangular matrix
    static Eigen::VectorXd Jacobi(const Eigen::MatrixXd& L, const Eigen::VectorXd& Y);

private:
    // Member variables
    double new_r;
    double new_q;
    double new_sigma;
    int new_T;
    int new_N;
    double new_K;
    double new_S0;
    int new_M;
    int new_R;
};

#endif
```

## Prefer initializers to assignment

Not only to make it easier for the compiler to generate efficient code, but also to allow `g++ -Weffc++` to warn you about any members you've forgotten to initialise:

```
LSM::LSM(const double r, const double q, const double sigma,
         const int T, const int N,
         const double K, const double S0,
         const int M, const int R)
    : new_r{r},
      new_q{q},
      new_sigma{sigma},
      new_T{T},
      new_N{N},
      new_K{K},
      new_S0{S0},
      new_M{M},
      new_R{R}
{
```

Renaming the members without the pointless `new_` prefix makes this even simpler:

```
LSM::LSM(const double r, const double q, const double sigma,
         const int T, const int N,
         const double K, const double S0,
         const int M, const int R)
    : r{r}, q{q}, sigma{sigma},
      T{T}, N{N},
      K{K}, S0{S0},
      M{M}, R{R}
{
```

That said, the members appear never to be used at all, so they can be eliminated.  Which then calls into question whether this is object-oriented code at all - what's the state+operations we're representing here?

## Fix the compilation errors

In both `Gaussian` and `LSM::Timepaths`, we attempt to use a `double` to instantiate an `Eigen::Matrix`, but an integer type is required.

`LSM::~LSM()` and `LSM::Gaussian` are declared but never defined.  We don't need a user-provided destructor, so just delete that, and change `Gaussian` to `LSM::Gaussian`.

## Reduce duplication

The only difference between `CallPayoff()` and `PutPayoff()` is the sign of the subtraction (`K - S(i)` vs `S(i) - K`).  Similarly for `Findcallpath()` and `Findputpath()`, and `Findcallreturn()` and `Findputreturn()`.  And there seems to be no visible difference between `Findcallprices()` and `Findputprices()`.

This does suggest that we're missing an indication of whether an option is a call or a put.  We can represent this as an additional argument, or perhaps (in the OO world) as an abstract method:

```
double PutOption::present_value(double present_price, double strike_price) override
{
    return strike_price - present_price;
}

double CallOption::present_value(double present_price, double strike_price) override
{
    return present_price - strike_price;
}
```

With these, all the valuation methods no longer need to be duplicated.

## Complete some functionality

There are no side-effects or tests of the code - it just constructs some objects, which are then ignored.  The program isn't ready for a full review.

Comment: For you first comment, should I not being writing this into a class at all? Why or why not?

Comment: OO design normally means encapsulating state into an object, together with the operations that act on that state.  But the members here are never used once set, and it seems to be a loose collection of *functions*.  There's nothing wrong with a group of functions, but it's a style of design that doesn't benefit from being a class.  I'll see if I can find time to show a more OO approach, later.

Comment: Thank you, I will continue with implementing your other suggestions and ill ask some questions if I do not understand

Comment: I keep getting different opinions on where to put the include files. By your comment are you suggesting I put them in the .cpp file instead of the header file since I am not using them in the header file?

Comment: Also, I have another question about your statement: Don't declare primitives const in method prototypes the fir example part I don't really understand, could you explain that further?

Comment: If you write `int f(const int x);` (typically in a header file) it's not giving any useful information to the caller.  It's useful to write `int f(const int x) { ... }` when you're writing the *definition*, and the signatures are identical (refer to the same function).  Similarly, I'd write `void g(char *s);` and perhaps `void g(char *const s) { ... }`.

Comment: If you include standard headers (or other library headers) in your header file, then everything that includes your header then includes all those library headers, whether or not they actually use any of their definitions.  My advice is to include as little as you can in any given header; anything you need for implementation should be included directly from the implementation file.  Also, that helps avoid accidents where code relies on those transitively-included headers - if you stop including them in the header, then that can break all the code that relied on those includes.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I will continue following most of your suggestions and make a new post once I finished the algorithm part and finalized all the code. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some general comments without really getting into what the code is supposed to do nor reading the linked-to post:

### Not every concept should be made a class

An "approach" or a "method" are not good things to write into classes. They're not something you can instantiate.

... and when I look at the names of your methods it's even more obvious that you should not have put those things into a class. In fact, it doesn't seem like your data members have anything to do with (most? all?) of your member functions

### Use meaningful names

Your names should convey meaning, not your comments. Instead of:

```
const double r = 0.04;          // Riskless interest rate
```

use:

```
const double riskless_interest_rate = 0.04;
```

single letters are for formulas in papers, not so much for code. Same goes for the class members, where it's even worse: `new_r`? Why, was there an "old" `r`?

Also,

```
// Generate the Laguerre Polynomials
Eigen::MatrixXd Laguerre(Eigen::VectorXd, const int);
```

should be (out of the class of course):

```
namespace polynomial_generators {

Eigen::MatrixXd Laguerre(
    Eigen::VectorXd  name_this_parameter, 
    int              and_this_one_too);

} // namespace polynomial_generators;
```

### Many arguments = Too many arguments

Looking at your main() function, I'm seeing:

```
LSM Option_value(foo, bar, baz, which, argument, is, this_now, i, forget, really);
```

and that makes me sad. :-(

### Abstractions must be consistent with each other

Something like this:

```
// Generate the Laguerre Polynomials
Eigen::MatrixXd Laguerre(Eigen::VectorXd, const int);
```

doen't make sense. A matrix is not a polynomial. Are you generating the coefficients? Then have the comment (actually, have the function name) say *that*. And that's not enough still, you'll probably want something like:

```
using PolynomialFamilyCoefficients = Eigen::MatrixXd;
```

or even write a wrapper/adapter class of some sort.

Comment: To your second comment, are you suggesting that all my sub-routines be in classes of themselves? I am new to writing classes and formal beautiful programming for that matter. I am a graduate student in mathematics that wishes to learn how to program better :)

Comment: @Wolfgang-1: They shouldn't be classes. They should probably just be free-standing functions (in appropriate namespaces). It's possibly, though unlikely, that you might want a `Polynomial` class inherited by a `polynomials::Laguerre` class with the constructor generating the coefficients. I can't say.

Comment: Also, I suggest you look for some YouTube talks by Herb Sutter and/or Bjarne Stroustrup about writing good C++. They've given a few in CppCon 2014/2015/2016, which go along with the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) project which you could also check out (but that one's a bit long, don't just read all of it.

Comment: Ok so all the functions should be out of the class and just stand along functions that the class constructor will use to price an American option contract?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1@: Put related code together. Maybe you'll have a "utility functions" cpp+h file pair which you use elsewhere (in multiple places even) which has, say, stuff related to polynomials and distributions, and another file with option-contract-related code which includes the .h file.

Comment: Okay, I am not understanding that really. All the sub-functions I need to use for pricing the American option within the actual algorithm part of the code. I am confused why I cannot have them inside the class or why that is bad coding in C++ terms.